# Is it possible for cookie to timeout in the middle of operation?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, cookies, timeout

Probably a dumb question.

For example if I create cookie with name `Permission`, value `true`, and expires in 3 minutes and I have Attribute `[CheckPermission]`.

```
[CheckPermission]
public ActionResult test()
{
     //do some shitty process that takes 5 minutes
     var flag = cookie["Permission"];
     //rest of code here
}
```

Ok so let's say you can only access `test` method if `Permission` cookie is set to `true`, `test` method contains some shitty process that took around 5 minutes, by the time it's done the cookie is already expired because it was set to expires in 3 minutes. Is this scenario possible or .NET automatically prevent this? If yes, then how do you prevent the cookie to not timeout in the middle of operation?

Thanks

Sorry for bad english

Comment: Why do you have an `Action Method` that is taking longer than 5 minutes to process? I would be more concerned with that.

Comment: it's just a made up situation.

Comment: Ok, since the `[CheckPermissions]` is done before the `Action Method` actually starts to process, as long as you are not doing any checks on the cookie within there it will be fine. So if it timed out it would be fine since the initial check has already been done and passed.

Comment: but what if I need the return the `flag` variable, it will cause the `flag` variable to have `null` value because of this.

Comment: Well, if you have an operation that takes 5 minutes and you only have a 3 minute cookie expiry. What do you expect to happen. There's not a way around it. Improve your code so it doesn't take as long to process OR increase the cookie expiry time.

Comment: Ok let me give you a real possible scenario, let's say I have a cookie that will expires in 30minutes, when it hits my method, 29mins59secs have passed, that means the cookie will expire in 1 second. If my method took more than 1 second then it will give me trouble if I need to get the value back. I made these 5 minutes example so it is easier to understand what I'm trying to say.